# Make a Vector3 field in the inspector behave as the Transform's position

Tags: unity, c#, editors

As the title suggests, I am looking to serialize on the Inspector a **Vector3** that behaves just like the **Transform's** position Vector3:

- If you modify the position **Vector3**, the **GameObject** positions itself according to the World Position.
- If you move the **GameObject** on the scene by picking the handles, the **GameObject** moves, and the position **Vector3** gets modified equal to the GameObject's position.

So, is there a way I can constrain a serialized **Vector3**, so if I modify it on the inspector I can change the **GameObject's** position, like this:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class LameExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 transformPosition;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(modifyingVectorOnInspector)
        transform.position = transformPosition;
        else if(gameObjectIsBeingMovedOnScene)
        transformPosition = transform.position;
    }
}
```

I've tried an approach using **Selection.contains(gameObject)**, but that does not take into account if it is dragged by the handles.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'd go with a custom inspector script for this, myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, using the `Reset` method to initialize the position when the component is added, and `OnValidate` to react to changes made in the inspector.

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class PositionMatch : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 position;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    void Reset() {
        position = transform.position;
    }

    void OnValidate() {
        if(transform.position != position) {
            UnityEditor.Undo.RecordObject(transform, "change position via variable.");
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }   
    
    void Update () {
        if(transform.position != position) {
            UnityEditor.Undo.RecordObject(this, "change position via Transform.");
            position = transform.position;
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Note that Unity's `==` operator for `Vector3`s has a little tolerance. If you don't want that, use `Vector3.Equals()` which uses exact equality.

Comment: Works as expected! Thank you very much. Sorry for the late vote.